# calculating probability of multiply of an inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, inequality, mathematical-modeling

I confronted a problem like this:
If we know the probabilistic inequality what would be the probability of one-side multiplication.
$$
Pr(T>t)<(1-t/c)
$$
the question asks for $x$
$$
Pr(T>kt)<x
$$
I believe $x$ will be $(1-t/c)^k$ based on the remainder of the text, but I have no reason to believe so.$$
Pr(T>kt)<(1-t/c)^k
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What is $T$? Is it a random variable that follows some distribution?

Comment: Thanks @duelspace. Yes T is a Random variable that follows some distribution.

Comment: Surely if $Pr(T>t) = 1-t/c$, then we must have $Pr(T > kt) = 1 - kt/c$ (so long as $kt<c$), shouldn't we?

Comment: @JohnBarber: yes, though with an inequality.  Presumably $t < c$ is a requirement for the initial inequality

Comment: @Henry you're right. t<c is a requirement. But,  is not <.

Comment: @YousefOleyaeimotlagh so $\Pr(T > kt) \le \max(0, 1 - kt/c)$ at least when $k>0$